# In "A Quiet Place 2" are there monsters in every continent?

Tags: post-apocalyptic, a-quiet-place

We know that monsters can't swim. A group has survived on a small island.

If those monsters came from space (as it seems from the ball of fire falling from heaven at the beginning of 2nd movie), they may not have arrived on every continent. And if so, the monsters wouldn't reach people in Australia for example.

However, we don't see any rescue mission or anyone trying to contact the survivors, not even in the newspapers.

Is there any hint that other countries or continents are safe from the monsters?

Answer (score 10):

Aliens landed on multiple continents with minutes time apart, as elaborated in [screenrant](https://screenrant.com/quiet-place-world-monsters-landing-sites-explained/);

> [image]

The article covered all the places which are not in the screenshot above either:

> **New England, USA**:  Emily Blunt as Evelyn and Monster in A Quiet Place
> 2 Opening
>
> **Shanghai, China:** A Quiet Place Part II’s opening sequence begins with
> Lee going to the pharmacy, where he sees a news broadcast documenting
> a mysterious meteor crash in Shanghai, China.
>
> **Mexico:** Although not on the whiteboard timestamps, A Quiet Place’s
> news clipping wall features an article about the monsters' meteor
> landing in Mexico, though the city wasn't revealed. The country was
> thought to be the original crash site until A Quiet Place 2's opening
> scene.
>
> **New Delhi, India:** On Lee's list of landings, he writes that monsters
> crashed in New Delhi, India at 19:42. New Delhi is at the top of the
> list, suggesting it may be the first place the monsters landed on
> Earth.
>
> **Singapore:** Only five minutes after A Quiet Place's monsters invaded
> New Delhi, the aliens crashed in the nearby Asian country Singapore at
> 19:47. With several confirmed crashes in populous Asian countries, the
> continent was hit harder than many other areas.
>
> **Bogota, Columbia:** Another timestamp on the whiteboard states that
> aliens landed in Bogota, Columbia at 19:52, only a few more seconds
> before Boston, MA was hit.
>
> **Moscow, Russia:** On Lee’s whiteboard, he wrote that
> monsters landed in Moscow, Russia at 19:54.
>
> **London, England:**  By Lee’s indication, London was an
> early crash location for the monsters on Earth. The whiteboard gives
> its timestamp as 19:49, almost 10 minutes ahead of A Quiet Place's New
> England crash.
>
> With South America confirmed, the only populated continent that could
> be safe is **Australia**, considering the movies never mention the
> country, and A Quiet Place 2 suggests islands can remain safe.

Comment: Everyone knows that the only safe place is Madagascar

Comment: @dna Shut. Down. Everything.